# How do you obtain Dole/Fresh Express bagged romaine lettuce with a Star-K on it?

Tags: product-recommendation, passover, marror-bitter-herbs, food

I know some stores tend to stock it, some don't.

One year before Pesach I tried contacting a produce wholesaler (we were having lots of company) regarding buying a case of it -- they said they contacted Dole and Dole said they would send a case WITH the Star-K kosher stamp. Well then the lettuce arrived and it didn't have the Star-K on it.

[According to the Star-K](http://star-k.org/kashrus/kk-passover-products.htm),

> VEG./SALADS, FRESH PKGD.
>   All fresh packaged salads bearing the Star-K symbol are Kosher for
>   Passover **without any additional Passover symbol**. 
>   Please note exception: Dole Very Veggie Salad Blend contains peas
>   which are Kitniyos and may not be used on Passover.

Updated in 2011: Fresh Express salads require Star-K-P for Passover.

So this would be ideal for easy marror for large crowds (if I could order a case of the giant bags of romaine).

Pesach or otherwise, any ideas? Somehow some stores are able to get it ...

Comment: I don't think you will be able to get it for Pesach.  I once called the Star K when Earthbound Farms had a hechsher, who told me that a kitnius based product is used to keep the cut leaves from becoming discolored.  If you can find the bug-free hechsher, you might be able to rinse the kitnios off, but consult your local orthodox rabbi.

Comment: @YDK, see above.

Comment: Perhaps I am misremembering which hashgacha it was.  I'm also misremembering the purpose of the preservative.  It was not for cut leaves, since I bought baby leaves.  Although I am clear about the brand, so I'll see if I can backtrack.

Comment: It was the star-k.  Perhaps their product has changed.  Another possibility is that EB farms is organic and they used a different preservative for them.  I haven't seen EB Farms with a hechsher for years which would explain why all of their kosher lettuce is OK for pesach.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Late breaking from the Star-K: March 30, 2011 FRESH EXPRESS bagged salads must bear a Star-K P to be considered kosher for Passover. http://www.star-k.org/alerts/alerts-March2011.htm

Answer (score 2):

Since 2-3 years ago when there was some whole supposed problem with the Romaine I have not seen anywhere the Dole / Fresh Express romaine with a Star-k. However I was in Queens this past week in [Aron's Kissena Farms](http://kissenafarms.com/) and they had Dole Romaine Lettuce with a Star-k.

Comment: @Gershon, it's become harder-to-find as of 3 years ago, as you say; but some stores (especially in large Jewish populations) often still have it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer your particular question, but I've seen at WalMart (here in St. Louis, for what it's worth) a store brand of bagged lettuce with the [K-ORC](http://www.kashrut.com/agencies/#CA) from San Francisco, which I don't know anything about. It may be worth looking into the K-ORC and calling WalMart.